# Python - how can I print n numbers per line of range by using for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, range

I have seen some examples of printing numbers per line, but I still didn't get it:(
I've tested \n but it didn't show up the result and I don't know why it won't work as I'm new to python, thank you so much!!!!!

My codes:

```
sum=0
sq=""

for i in range (0+2,1000+1,2):
   sum+=i
   if i<1000:
      sq=sq+str(i)+","
    
   else:
      sq=sq+str(i)
print(sq, end="\n")
print("Sum of all even numbers within 1 and 1000 =",sum)
```

My output:

```
2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36,38,40,42,44,46,48,50,52,54,56,58,60,62,64,66,68,70,72,74,76,78,80,82,84,86,88,90,92,94,96,98,100,102,104,106,108,110,112,114,116,118,120,122,124,126,128,130,132,134,136,138,140,142,144,146,148,150,152,154,156,158,160,162,164,166,168,170,172,174,176,178,180,182,184,186,188,190,192,194,196,198,200,202,204,206,208,210,212,214,216,218,220,222,224,226,228,230,232,234,236,238,240,242,244,246,248,250,252,254,256,258,260,262,264,266,268,270,272,274,276,278,280,282,284,286,288,290,292,294,296,298,300,302,304,306,308,310,312,314,316,318,320,322,324,326,328,330,332,334,336,338,340,342,344,346,348,350,352,354,356,358,360,362,364,366,368,370,372,374,376,378,380,382,384,386,388,390,392,394,396,398,400,402,404,406,408,410,412,414,416,418,420,422,424,426,428,430,432,434,436,438,440,442,444,446,448,450,452,454,456,458,460,462,464,466,468,470,472,474,476,478,480,482,484,486,488,490,492,494,496,498,500,502,504,506,508,510,512,514,516,518,520,522,524,526,528,530,532,534,536,538,540,542,544,546,548,550,552,554,556,558,560,562,564,566,568,570,572,574,576,578,580,582,584,586,588,590,592,594,596,598,600,602,604,606,608,610,612,614,616,618,620,622,624,626,628,630,632,634,636,638,640,642,644,646,648,650,652,654,656,658,660,662,664,666,668,670,672,674,676,678,680,682,684,686,688,690,692,694,696,698,700,702,704,706,708,710,712,714,716,718,720,722,724,726,728,730,732,734,736,738,740,742,744,746,748,750,752,754,756,758,760,762,764,766,768,770,772,774,776,778,780,782,784,786,788,790,792,794,796,798,800,802,804,806,808,810,812,814,816,818,820,822,824,826,828,830,832,834,836,838,840,842,844,846,848,850,852,854,856,858,860,862,864,866,868,870,872,874,876,878,880,882,884,886,888,890,892,894,896,898,900,902,904,906,908,910,912,914,916,918,920,922,924,926,928,930,932,934,936,938,940,942,944,946,948,950,952,954,956,958,960,962,964,966,968,970,972,974,976,978,980,982,984,986,988,990,992,994,996,998,1000
Sum of all even numbers within 1 and 1000 = 250500
```

How can we achieve an output like this by using for loop:

```
2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40
42, 44, 46, 48, 50, 52, 54, 56, 58, 60, 62, 64, 66, 68, 70, 72, 74, 76, 78, 80
…
922, 924, 926, 928, 930, 932, 934, 936, 938, 940, 942, 944, 946, 948, 950, 952, 954,956, 958, 960
962, 964, 966, 968, 970, 972, 974, 976, 978, 980, 982, 984, 986, 988, 990, 992, 994, 996, 998, 1000
Sum of all even numbers within 1 and 1000 = 250500
```

Comment: Do you want a line break every 20 numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

firstly, `sum` is a protected keyword since it is the list sum function, so don't call any variables "sum".

to split the string, try:

```py
sum=0
sq=""

for i in range (0+2,1000+1,2):
   sum+=i
   if i<1000:
      sq=sq+str(i)+", "
    
   else:
      sq=sq+str(i)
   if i % 40 == 0:
      sq += "\n"
print(sq, end="\n")
print("Sum of all even numbers within 1 and 1000 =",sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

##### solution

```py
sum=0
for i in range(2,1001,2):
    sum+=i
    if i%20 == 2: print("\n{}".format(i),end="")    # print new line per 20 numbers
    else: print(", {}".format(i),end="")
print("\nSum of all even numbers within 1 and 1000 =",sum)
```

- Output:

  ```bash
  2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20 
  22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40 
  ...
  962, 964, 966, 968, 970, 972, 974, 976, 978, 980 
  982, 984, 986, 988, 990, 992, 994, 996, 998, 1000
  Sum of all even numbers within 1 and 1000 = 250500
  ```

---

##### another solution with better run time performance

```py
print("".join(["\n"+str(i) if i%20==2 else ", "+str(i) for i in range(2,1001,2)]))
print("\nSum of all even numbers within 1 and 1000 =",sum(range(2,1001,2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Uisng `textwrap` [Inbuilt Library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html)

```
import textwrap
import re

sum=0
sq=""


for i in range (0+2,1000+1,2):
   sum+=i
   if i<1000:
      sq=sq+str(i)+","
    
   else:
      sq=sq+str(i)
#print(sq, end="\n")

print('\n'.join(textwrap.wrap(sq, 20)))#Mask n here

      
print("Sum of all even numbers within 1 and 1000 =",sum)
```

#output

```
2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30
,32,34,36,38,40,42,44,46,48,50,52,54,56,
58,60,62,64,66,68,70,72,74,76,78,80,82,8
4,86,88,90,92,94,96,98,100,102,104,106,1
08,110,112,114,116,118,120,122,124,126,1
28,130,132,134,136,138,140,142,144,146,1
48,150,152,154,156,158,160,162,164,166,1
68,170,172,174,176,178,180,182,184,186,1
88,190,192,194,196,198,200,202,204,206,2
08,210,212,214,216,218,220,222,224,226,2
28,230,232,234,236,238,240,242,244,246,2
48,250,252,254,256,258,260,262,264,266,2
68,270,272,274,276,278,280,282,284,286,2
88,290,292,294,296,298,300,302,304,306,3
08,310,312,314,316,318,320,322,324,326,3
28,330,332,334,336,338,340,342,344,346,3
48,350,352,354,356,358,360,362,364,366,3
68,370,372,374,376,378,380,382,384,386,3
88,390,392,394,396,398,400,402,404,406,4
08,410,412,414,416,418,420,422,424,426,4
28,430,432,434,436,438,440,442,444,446,4
48,450,452,454,456,458,460,462,464,466,4
68,470,472,474,476,478,480,482,484,486,4
88,490,492,494,496,498,500,502,504,506,5
08,510,512,514,516,518,520,522,524,526,5
28,530,532,534,536,538,540,542,544,546,5
48,550,552,554,556,558,560,562,564,566,5
68,570,572,574,576,578,580,582,584,586,5
88,590,592,594,596,598,600,602,604,606,6
08,610,612,614,616,618,620,622,624,626,6
28,630,632,634,636,638,640,642,644,646,6
48,650,652,654,656,658,660,662,664,666,6
68,670,672,674,676,678,680,682,684,686,6
88,690,692,694,696,698,700,702,704,706,7
08,710,712,714,716,718,720,722,724,726,7
28,730,732,734,736,738,740,742,744,746,7
48,750,752,754,756,758,760,762,764,766,7
68,770,772,774,776,778,780,782,784,786,7
88,790,792,794,796,798,800,802,804,806,8
08,810,812,814,816,818,820,822,824,826,8
28,830,832,834,836,838,840,842,844,846,8
48,850,852,854,856,858,860,862,864,866,8
68,870,872,874,876,878,880,882,884,886,8
88,890,892,894,896,898,900,902,904,906,9
08,910,912,914,916,918,920,922,924,926,9
28,930,932,934,936,938,940,942,944,946,9
48,950,952,954,956,958,960,962,964,966,9
68,970,972,974,976,978,980,982,984,986,9
88,990,992,994,996,998,1000
Sum of all even numbers within 1 and 1000 = 250500
```

Also

```
import textwrap
import re

sum=0
sq=""


for i in range (0+2,1000+1,2):
   sum+=i
   if i<1000:
      sq=sq+str(i)+","
    
   else:
      sq=sq+str(i)
#print(sq, end="\n")


print (textwrap.fill(sq, 20))
      
print("Sum of all even numbers within 1 and 1000 =",sum)
```

#same output

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
lst = [i for i in range(2,1001,2)]
for i in range(0, len(lst), 20):
    print(','.join(str(i) for i in lst[i:i+20]))
print(f'Sum of all even numbers within 1 and 1000 : {sum(lst)}')
```